# fill some methodes in LinkedList in C#

Tags: c#

hello please i have an homework and I'm searched  all the internet and i can't find any solutions please i need some one to help me to do this homework please.
this is the class

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public Node head;
    public int size;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void Append(student d)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public Node Remove()
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public Node Search(int key)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public Node SearchPrevious(int key)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public void Insert(student s, int previousKey)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public void Delete(int key)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }

    public void PrintLinkedList()
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }
```

and this is the two others classes

```
public class Node
{
    public student data;
    public Node link;

    public Node()
    {
        data = null;
        link = null;
    }

    public Node(student s, Node p)
    {
        data = s;
        link = p;
    }
```

the two and class

```
  public class student
{
    public int TNumber;
    public string Name;
    public string Advisor;
    public student(int t, string n, string a)
    {
        TNumber = t;
        Name = n;
        Advisor = a;
    }
}
```

i now this an homework but i find stackoverflow is my last solution please help me

Comment: If this is a homework you should do it yourself to get better understanding of what is `LinkedList` data structure, how it works, in which cases you should use it in real world projects etc... Try to do it yourself and if you stuck upon particular problem get back to SO and ask a question.

Comment: What did you try? What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Now that you've given us the question, why don't you add in what you've got so far. Right now it looks like you haven't even made an effort.

Comment: `I'm searched all the internet and i can't find any solutions`  Yes, it a very unique homework.....

Comment: guys there is nothing wrong with asking homework questions - usually you don't answer it 100% at first but it's no reason to downvote

Comment: @Carsten read the OP's comment below: `help me to complete the other please` He doesn't look for help. he wants to get it done.

Comment: @Eser it's a comment to my answer and I already reacted - still this is no reason to be offensive to a new member - this was discussed hundreds of times already and we as the SO community decided that a valid question does not get invalid just because it's homework - if it's a good question is another issue of course

Comment: for example there are 3 `unclear what is asked` votes - all **those** are invalid because it's very clear what is asked - the voters just did not find a "want to close because I want to punish for asking to do the homework" reason ... ;)

Comment: and sadly things like this happen in the C# parts here all the time - it's almost toxic - no contrast this with smaller subcommunities and I think we have to do something get get this more friendly again

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you out with the first one a bit:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public Node head;
    public int size;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void Append(student d)
    {
        // FILL THIS METHOD
    }
```

first let me say that the structure is really strange - all is linked in a mess (and I think maybe your teacher should think hard about his/her design decisions here) - but well I guess we have to go with it.

As you only got a `student d` you can only create a new node with it, well for this you need it's `link` the value is not hard - it's the student but the node is harder - you have to find the end of the list first, so let's do this with a simple loop:

```
public class LinkedList
{
   // ...
   public Node FindTail ()
   {
       var tail = head;
       while (tail != null && tail.link != null)
           tail = tail.link;
       return tail;
   }
```

good - with this Append is not hard:

```
    public void Append(student d)
    {
        var oldTail = FindTail();
        var newTail = new Node(d, oldTail);
        if (oldTail == null)
           head = newTail;
        else
           oldTail.link = newTail;

        // oh wait there is something missing here
        // hint: I ignored the size ... you should do something
        // about it
    }
```

that's it - this should be about right and you should be able to figure out the rest yourself.

**don't forget to set the size**

Comment: help me to complete the other please

Comment: no sorry - I'll help if you show me what you tried and where it failed but I will not do your complete homework